# How to delete special characters and a specific word from a json/string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove a specific word from a JSON file.

I have this to remove special characters like `: , {} []`

```
  JSON.stringify(csv, null, 2).replace(
    /[!@#$^&%*()+=[\]/{}|:<>?,.\\-]/g,
    '',
  ),
```

but then there is the word `"data"`, how can I add that word to be removed from the string in that regex above?

And also I would like to remove the `""` around the strings.
Like `"hola"` I want it to be only `hola`

Comment: Add " in your character list `/["!@#$^&%*()+=[\]/{}|:<>?,.\\-]/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the **x|y** pattern:

```
/"data":|[!"@#$^&%*()+=[\]/{}|:<>?,.\\-]/g
```

```js
var csv = {
    "data":[
        { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
        { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
        { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
    ]
}
var x = JSON.stringify(csv, null, 2).replace(/"data":|[!"@#$^&%*()+=[\]/{}|:<>?,.\\-]/g, '');

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var result = str.replace(/\bdata\b|["!@#$^&%*()+=[\]/{}|:<>?,.\\-]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the regex in kind of the opposite way.  This regex is the word data, or not the characters within [^]

```
/(data|[^a-zA-Z0-9,.; ])/g
```

Comment: I can still see the word data

Comment: I removed the word boundaries, as it is looking for whitespace and not ""

Comment: Keep in mind this will remove accented characters, too which is likely not what the OP expects

Comment: In case my solution does not clearly show this all characters in the [^] are what will be left, any chars you don't want removed should be included in there.

Comment: Yes. With this solution it is actually un-formatting the JSON file as it was printed before.